# Problems seeing my xdv changes in Plone

Tags: plone, xdv

It seems like lots of people are using xdv successfully so this must be something I'm not getting about xdv. I am running 4.0.3 on my local server (Mac). I have a xdv theme running in Plone (diazo.example.com) and I am trying to modify the styles. I can see my changes on apache and DW but they do not appear in Plone. I have debug mode on. I tried deactivating and activating the theme and emptying the cache. No luck, the site does not update. I thought it was 'easy' to make changes on-the-fly with xdv but this has me stumped. I didn't register the stylesheets in CSS registry. Is that a critical step or optional?

On another note, is it worth it to switch to diazo and plone.app.theming? What are the major benefits of doing so?

Thanks!

Elaine

Answer (score 4):

I absolutely recommend that you switch to diazo and plone.app.theming. This is most easily done by starting with Plone 4.1.x instead of Plone 4.0.x. Get a copy at http://plone.org/products/plone/releases/4.1

Then, using buildout, install plone.app.theming. You may have a few issues with lxml, but since you've already done xdv I figure you've conquered that already.